# Tensorflow: Equivalent of scikit-learn's pairwise_kernels in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, cosine-similarity, pairwise

I am trying to find `cosine similarity` between two set of embeddings. I calculated it using `pairwise_kernels` from `scikit-learn` but now I am trying to leverage GPU, hence I am looking for the Tensorflow equivalent of `pairwise_kernels`. This is what I did using `scikit-learn`:

```
sim_elements = pairwise_kernels(input_array, orig_array, metric = 'cosine', n_jobs = -1)
```

I searched online and came across tensorflow `pairwise_distances` but that's not what I am trying to achieve. I am trying to achieve one-to-many similairity than one-to-one similarity. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correct, I think you could just use the CosineSimilarity Loss-Function from tf.keras.losses:
https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/losses/CosineSimilarity

But take care, they swapped the output that it works as a Loss-Funtion. So -1 is maximum similarity and 1 minimal similarity.